# variable undefined when using alert()

Tags: javascript

```
I have this script:

<script>

var prop = document.getElementById('div1').firstChild.getAttribute("id");

function aler()
{
    alert(prop);
}
</script>
```

and out of the script tag:

```
<div id="div1">some content</div>
<button onclick="aler()"></button>
```

Can someone explain to me why when I click the button it says: "undefined"

Correction:
in the div i drag a picture:

```
  <img  id="C" src="C.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="91px" height="91px">
```

for example.

Answer (score 4):

The first child of div1 is a text node. It has no id.

EDIT

As to your correction, if the resulting HTML looks *anything* like this, then the first child is still a text node:

```
<div id="div1">
    <img  id="C" etc.>
</div>
```

because text includes tabs, spaces, and returns. I'm not sure how drag/drop affects that.

Comment: function passName(locationID)
{
  el1 = document.getElementById('div1').firstChild.getAttribute("id");
 
 el2 = document.getElementById('div2').firstChild.getAttribute("id");
 locationID.innerHTML=el1+"and"+el2;
 alert(el1); 
}

that is a function, and el1 and el2 are defined like the prop variable. But when I alert them, a value is shown... and sorry for the big number of corrections - I can't explain very good...

Answer (score 1):

In the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), there are various kinds of "nodes." Your `<div id="div1">some content</div>` markup defines **two** nodes: An [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) that's a `div`, and its first (and only) child, a [`Text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) node containing the text you have within the `div`. The `Text` node has no `id`. The `div` element has an `id`, but the text node does not.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('div1').firstChild` is the text `some content`. When you call `getAttribute("id")` on that, since plain text had no `id`, you're going to get `undefined`.

Comment: OK, little correction - after a drag and drob operation there is a image in the div: